# Como eu pego o valor de cada checkbox que está dentro de um loop?

Tags: php, html

Bom dia galera, preciso de ajuda :(
É o seguinte, eu preciso deletar vários registros de uma só vez pra isso preciso selecionar o ID de cada registro, então eu fiz um input com checkbox dentro do loop desse jeito:

```
<form method="POST" id="formDeletarMsg" action="deletarMsg.php">
   <input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="<?php echo $idMsg; ?>">                          
</form>
```

Botão submit está fora do formulário, estou usando javascript pois ele irá ficar no rodapé da section.

E estou usando um foreach para exibir os dados de cada checkbox, ele até funciona, só que exibe apenas o primeiro checkbox marcado, se eu marcar o segundo ou o terceiro não exibe nada, se eu marcar o primeiro exibe:

```
if(isset($_POST['msg'])){
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
foreach($msg as $key => $value){
    echo $key . "<br>";
    echo $value;
}
var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galera, a burrada que eu fiz foi colocar o formulario dentro do while, por isso estava exibindo apenas o primeiro checkbox marcado, o formulario tem que estar fora do while mas o input tem que estar dentro. **RESOLVIDO!!!**

```
<form method="POST" id="formDeletarMsg" action="deletarMsg.php">
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlMps)):
                        $idMsg = $row['idMsg'];
                        $assunto = utf8_encode($row['assunto']);
                        $usuario = $row['usuario'];
                        $visualizou = $row['visualizou'];
                        $dataMsg = utf8_encode($row['dataMsg']);

                ?>
                <li>
                    <span><a <?php if($visualizou == 0){ echo "class='negrito'";}?> href="visualizarMp.php?id=<?php echo $idMsg; ?>"><?php echo substr($assunto, 0, 30); ?></a>   por <strong><?php echo $usuario; ?></strong> - <?php echo $dataMsg; ?></span>
                    <div class="right">

                            <input type="checkbox" name="deletar[]" value="<?php echo $idMsg; ?>">


                    </div>
                </li>

                <?php
                    endwhile;
                ?>
                 </form>
```

Comment: Olá Vinicius, você não quer postar um pedaço de código para ajudar outros usuários que tenham o mesmo problema?

Comment: É só tirar o formulario de dentro do loop, vou editar minha resposta